# pg_restore: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a RoR application hosted on Heroku using a Postgresql database and have been using the PG Backups tool to backup the database from my application on to my local machine. Since the application is still in development, it helps me from a programming standpoint to bring down the changes my colleagues are making to the database. I have been successfully using PG Backups to capture and restore for months but lately, when I run my typical commands as seen here:

```
$curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url --app XXXXX`
$pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U XXXXX -d XXXXX_development latest.dump
```

I am getting this error after the curl command goes through:

```
-bash: pg_restore: command not found
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Obviously the problem is that I can't restore the downloaded backup.

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like something changed in your local environment, and now `pg_restore`, a client command tool bundled with postgres alongside pg_dump and psql, is not available.

Sounds like you need to set your PATH correctly.

Try finding the correct `pg_restore` in your system with maybe `sudo find / -name pg_restore`, and after you do add it's directory to PATH.

Finally, what you're doing could possibly be accomplished with a simpler `heroku pg:pull`, which takes a backup from your heroku database and restores it locally all in one command (but also uses pg_dump/pg_restore, so those need to be available as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'm a novice programmer, I tried finding resources to help me add pg_restore to PATH but nothing was working (I've never done anything like that before).

I'm not sure what operating system you use but I am running Mac OSX Mavericks. If you're running on Mac, could you let me know how you would go about performing this fix?

Comment: How did you install postgres? If you have not installed postgres locally, then do that first. I'd recommend http://postgresapp.com/ and follow its docs for the PATH fix